# openCV don't render my draw, just a simple black window

Tags: python, opencv

I just wrote a simple code to draw a circle when i click down, but I only see a black image and not my circle

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,0,0),-1)

cv2.namedWindow(winname='my_drawing')
cv2.setMouseCallback('my_drawing', draw_circle)
img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.int32)
while True:
    cv2.imshow('my_drawing', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can someone help me pls? My IDE is Pycharm

EDIT:

I fixed that, but I don't know why this works. I changed np.int32 to np.uint8 and changed this function:

```
def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,0,0),-1)
        cv2.imshow('my_drawing', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Why I need to use .imshow() 2 times? Why I need to use np.uint8?

Comment: What do you mean by this: "imshow() 2 times"?

Comment: You need an additional `cv2.imshow()` to display the updated image.

Comment: @barny hummm okkk that's it. I thought I just needed one because i saw some videos on jupyter, and they just use on `.imshow()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your image type as `uint8`.

```py
img = np.zeros(shape=(512, 512, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

From the [answers.opencv.org](https://answers.opencv.org/question/74670/whyare-all-the-images-in-uint8-data-type/) and [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html):

> The reason why Uint8 is very common is because it is the standard way to display images, in which each pixel ranges between 0 and 255. If it is a gray scale image, a pixel with value 0 is black and a pixel with value 255 is white, and gray in the middle

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Q: Why I need to use np.uint8?

A: A pixel is usually stored as a collection of 3 bytes, 1 for each color (RGB). A np.uint8 is equivalent to a byte in this case. A np.uint32 is 4 bytes and is too large to use as a color value.

"Current typical display adapters use up to 24-bits of information for each pixel: 8-bit per component multiplied by three components (see the Digital representations section below (24bits = 2563, each primary value of 8 bits with values of 0–255)" --https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model